# How to get a data in a Text field in SSRS if the dataset does not contain the value?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have four dataset in SSRS. They are below-

POHeader- Company, PONum
PODetail- Company, PONum, POLine
PORel- Company, JobNum, POLine, PONum, ProjectID
JobHead- Company, JobCOde, JobNum, PersonID, ProjectID

There is a text field (Project Lead) in the POHeader in which I want to show the person ID (Project Lead Name). However, POHeader does not contain any PersonID field. One way I am thinking to do that is relate POHeader and PORel tables that will match PONum and return JobNum and the Returned JobNUm will be matched with JobHead.JobNum.

If they match and then the PersonID will be returned, which will be shown in the text field (Project Lead) in the POHeader.

However, I have little experience in SQL. Would be great if someone can help me in this regard.

LOOKUP function can be a solution here, but comparing one return value with an existing value of a different data seems challenging for me.

UPDATE on the SQL Code-

```
="SELECT
    [PlannerID].[JobHead_PersonID] as [JobHead_PersonID]
from  (select 
    [POHeader].[PONum] as [POHeader_PONum],
     [JobHead].[PersonID] as [JobHead_PersonID],
    [JobHead].[JobNum] as [JobHead_JobNum]
from Erp.POHeader as POHeader
 inner join Erp.PODetail as PODetail on 
    POHeader.Company = PODetail.Company
    and POHeader.PONum = PODetail.PONUM
inner join Erp.PORel as PORel on 
    PODetail.Company = PORel.Company
    and PODetail.PONUM = PORel.PONum
    and PODetail.POLine = PORel.POLine
inner join Erp.JobHead as JobHead on 
    PORel.Company = JobHead.Company
    and PORel.JobNum = JobHead.JobNum)  as PlannerID
  right outer join Erp.POHeader as POHeader1 on 
    POHeader1.PONum = PlannerID.POHeader_PONum 
    POHeader.Company = PODetail.Company
     and POHeader.PONum = PODetail.PONUM
inner join Erp.PORel as PORel on 
   PODetail.Company = PORel.Company
    and PODetail.PONUM = PORel.PONum
   and PODetail.POLine = PORel.POLine
 inner join Erp.JobHead as JobHead on 
    PORel.Company = JobHead.Company
    and PORel.JobNum = JobHead.JobNum)  as PlannerID
right outer join Erp.POHeader as POHeader1 on 
    POHeader1.PONum = PlannerID.POHeader_PONum"
```

SQL Code that I have written to return the PersonID, but  I need to know two things-

1. Where to put this subquery?
2. How to return the value from the subquery in the Project Lead text field using an expression?

Will be grateful if I can get some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: The best way to get help on stackoverflow is to show that you've tried something. Have you tried writing the SQL query or any statements in SSRS? You can probably  do  what you are asking easier in SQL, but the logic is possible in SSRS.

Comment: Hi Steve 

This is the query that I have written

1. =Lookup(Fields!PONum.Value, Fields!PONum.Value, Fields!JobNum.Value, "POHeader")

This query returns the Job Number (JobNum) after it matches the PONum which is saved in a text field

2. =Lookup(ReportItems!Textbox14.Value, Fields!JobNum.value, Fields!PersonID.value, "POHeader")

This query matches the jobNum and it is supposed to return the PersonID (Project Lead). However, it does not. I am possibly doing something wrong here.

Comment: That isn't a SQL query.

Comment: Sorry, it the expression I have typed within the text field to match two fields of dataset 1 and dataset2 and return a 3rd value and again matches the 3rd value with a field i dataset 3. I have identified the problem now. The value that is I am trying to get from dataset 3 is not actually within dataset 3

Comment: Do you have access to modify the SQL. While you can join multiple datasets in SSRS it is way easier to write a good SQL Statement then to do that type of logic in SSRS? If you have the SQL, post it along with sample data.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to modify the SQL. That's the main issue. That's why I am trying to implement a logic to extract the field data. I will come up with a more concrete view of the dataset with example so that I can get an answer. Thanks for your kind suggestions mate

Comment: Hi @SteveB

My SQL code is updated in the post.

I have written a SQL code which works as a subquery and brings up the PersonID from JObHead table. After then it matches the POHeader_projectID and JobHeader_ProjectID and returns the PersonID.

However, I could not show the value in the Project Leade field where I want to show the PersonID value.

My 2 questions are-

1. Where do I need to put this SQL subquery that returns the personID?
2. How to return the value of PersonID in the ProjectLead text field?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS uses Datasets to get data from a database, and each field in a data set can be displayed on a report.  To add a field to a dataset, it must be returned by the underlying data set query.  View the data set properties and look at the query.  If it is of the form "select a,b,c from table", add the field you want to the column list (a,b,c etc).  If it is a stored procedure, find someone who can edit that procedure to include your missing field.  When you have done this, refresh the field list for the Dataset.  Your new field should be usesable in the report now.  Of course, if you have broken the sql for the data set you will need to find someone who knows the underlying database to help you.

Comment: Hi mate
This is the query that I have written 1. =Lookup(Fields!PONum.Value, Fields!PONum.Value, Fields!JobNum.Value, "POHeader") This query returns the Job Number (JobNum) after it matches the PONum which is saved in a text field 2. =Lookup(ReportItems!Textbox14.Value, Fields!JobNum.value, Fields!PersonID.value, "POHeader") This query matches the jobNum and it is supposed to return the PersonID (Project Lead). However, it does not. I am possibly doing something wrong here.

Comment: Hi @Programnik

I have added a SQL query. If you can have a look that would be great help for me. Thanks mate

Comment: Hi @Programnik, I think your suggestion is correct. So, I have added the subquery in the underlying dataset query. However, I have probably made some mistake in there. I am unable to get the report view now.